# Can I use "Firstly" while writing email? Is this a correct word to use in communication?

Tags: word-choice

I had a problem while writing emails where I want to tell few things in order.
I had used "Firstly" in the email but I am not very sure is it a correct way to talk or write.

Comment: What did your dictionary tell you? Please note that questions that don''t show evidence of adequate research  are off-topic here.

Comment: Just "First", "Second" etc.

Comment: OK @TusharRaj . Lets consider a scenario where I want to describe 3 things to the user. So in that situation can I say - Firstly -- you do this , Secondly -- You do this like that way?

Comment: @TusharDiwan: No. `Firstly` is normally used to introduce points in an argument/explanation. In your scenario, you should go with `first`. And after that, `then`.

Comment: "First" is the simplest. You may emphasize it by writing "First of all".

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think the usage is idiomatic...help me out here...in AmE we use first, and I think in BrE firstly is used.  At least that's what I have always seen in textbooks.

Comment: @michael_timofeev look at the answer posted, it actually explains when the two forms are not interchangeable. Firstly, I think people tend to prefer *first* when there is a list of points or instructions. Secondly, it's important not to mix the two adverbs, don't start with *firstly* and then write *second*.  Text books will also recommend students to not add *thirdly*, *fourthly* and so on. And finally, it depends on whether you're writing a formal paper, an English exam, or if it's just to a colleague or friend. (*groan*)

Comment: @michael_timofeev no idea if *firstly* is preferred in BrEng. I wouldn't think so today. But maybe in the past it was so.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I remember facing this question in a presentations class I was teaching.  I looked through some textbooks, and online and answers seemed to indicate that first was preferred in AmE.  Nowadays I tell Sts, "Whatever you like, just don't mix 'em." (As you mentioned.)

Comment: @michael_timofeev Found this answer which might interest you http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/886/firstly-secondly-or-first-second/890#890

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you Mari Lou.  Chiao!

Answer (score 0):

[As pointed out in the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258018/can-i-use-firstly-while-writing-email-is-this-a-correct-word-to-use-in-commun#comment565895_258018), the most common way of listing, in order, an agenda of things in an email would be to use `first`, `then`, and then perhaps a concluding adverb.

These are typically called [conjunctive adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb), and you may want to have a look at [this comparison](http://grammarist.com/usage/firstly-secondly-thirdly/).

> Because ordinal numbers (i.e., first, second, third, fourth, etc.) function as both adjectives and adverbs, the -ly adverbs firstly, secondly, thirdly, fourthly, and so on are superfluous.

[Another perspective on adding *-ly*](http://ontariotraining.net/first-versus-firstly/) to first, second, etc.

Comment: Awesom !!! Alex L , this helped a lot to clear that concept :) Nice response :) Thanks Dude

Comment: @TusharDiwan if you feel this answer is suitable for your question, it's always best to mark an answer as Correct!

Comment: But it's also best not to answer questions without first checking to see that they've not been asked and answered before.